# which meaning of the word 'would ' is used here?

Tags: word-meaning, modal-verbs

In which meaning 'would ' is used here in the following sentences :

> 1. Who would have thought her capable of murder? (In which meaning 'would ' is used here ?)
> 2. They were in the same class, so they would have known each other.
> 3. He grew so angry, it seemed he would explode.

Comment: I don't know if it's just me, but would you please clarify your question?

Comment: I've clearly asked my question

Answer (score 2):

In all of you examples **would** could be substituted with **might**, with the definition

> "expressing a conjecture, opinion, or hope"

In your cases a conjecture.

Comment: How it is conjucture ? Could you please explain

Comment: @yubrajsharma http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/conjecture